# String copy not working for rotating an array of array of string

Tags: arrays, c, string, char

I have an array of array of string, written in C as a global variable:

```
static char strList[10][20][30]; /* Used 10, 20, 30 for easier comunication */
```

Which would be storing something structured like this (actual content varies)

```
[["word1", "word2", ..., "word20" ],  /* line 1 */
["ward1", "wsrd2", ..., "wdrd20" ],   /* line 2 */
...
["wasd1", "qwer2", ..., "uijk20" ]]   /* line 10 */
```

And I wanted to have a rotation function that moves line 1 into line 2, line 2 into line 3... and discard line 10. I wrote it like this:

```
void rotateList(){
    int i, j;
    
    for(j = 10-2; j >0; j--){
        for(i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            strcpy(strList[j+1][i], strList[j][i]); 
            /* Copy lower index into higher ones? */
        }
        strcpy(strList[j+1][i+1], "\0");
    }
}
```

It compiles and runs, but doesn't seem to be copying. What was in line 1 didn't move into line 2 and the list instead turned empty.

What might be wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: C arrays are 0 based, so the first line is "line 0".

Comment: Change `j > 0` to `j >= 0`

Comment: @Barmar Oops, that's kind of a stupid mistake I just made. Thank you for pointing it out.  Should I delete this question?

Comment: The second `strcpy()` is also wrong. If you want to empty all the strings in line 1, you need another `for` loop

Comment: `"\0"` is the same as `""`

Comment: You can also empty the first line with `memset(strList[0], 0, sizeof(strList[0]))`

Comment: @Barmar: `"\0"` has the same effect in this case as `""` but it is a different string: it has 2 null bytes instead of just one for `""`.

Comment: @chqrlie The second null byte is irrelevant in any situation where it's used as a string, since all string operations stop at the first null. You could tell the difference with something like `sizeof`.

Comment: @Barmar: I agree, hence `"\0"` acts the same as `""`, but they are not exactly the same.

Comment: I know. I didn't feel the need to write a treatise on equivalence in a throwaway comment. All I meant was that he could write `strcpy(..., "");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop is incorrect: you do not reset the first line at the end, but instead access a string beyond the end of the current row at each iteration.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <string.h>

static char strList[DIM1][DIM2][DIM3];

void rotateList() {
    for (size_t j = DIM1; j --> 1; ) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < DIM2; i++) {
            strcpy(strList[j][i], strList[j - 1][i]); 
        }
    }
    /* reset the first row */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < DIM2; i++) {
        strList[0][i][0] = '\0';
    }
}
```

Note that you might get better performance with a massive block copy:

```
void rotateList() {
    memmove(strList[1][0], strList[0][0], sizeof(strList) - sizeof(strList[0]));
    memset(strList[0][0], 0, sizeof(strList[0]));
}
```

Comment: I've never heard of `memmove` before, looks like I've missed a lot in C, thank you for the explanation! :D

Comment: @AmarthGûl, you can also upvote, you know ;)

Comment: @AmarthGûl: `memmove` copies a block of memory from an address to another and operates correctly even if the source and destination spans overlap, which is the case here.